# Generate additional column indicating substring match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with `column1` as city name and country name (please see below image). I want to create an output column which says 'correct' if it finds 'US' in `column1`, else 'wrong'?. How can I do this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution with the [regexp match operator **`~`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN column1 ~ 'US' THEN 'correct' ELSE 'wrong' END
FROM   tbl;
```